# Dynamic Reports XLS,CSV

Tags: java, csv, report, xls, dynamic-reports

Such a problem created reports using the DynamicReports engine in PDF everything is OK, in CSV and XLS, some sort of crapperblack

CSV

[image]

Comment: That looks like a character encoding error. Which character encoding is the original document using (ASCII, UTF-8, something else?) and what character encoding are you telling the CSV/XLS translator to use?

Comment: thanks , i set utf-8 in exporter and it works